# How to set docker container name in Pycharm Docker Interpreter

Tags: docker, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm (2021.2.2) on MacOS (11.6).
I want to specify `--name` when using the Docker interpreter.
However, when I entered `--name` in `Edit Docker container Settings`, I got an error like this and could not set it.

[image]

How can I set the container name?

I know it can be set in docker-compose.yaml. I want to specify the container name using Docker Interpreter.

If anyone knows, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. `--name` position was wrong.

This is works fine!

```
--name container_name --entrypoint= --rm --network=my_network
```

[image]